# I cannot install kivy in Anaconda Windows

Tags: python, kivy, anaconda

I am trying to install kivy in Anaconda, but the following message showed up:

```
-(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\USER>conda install -c krisvanneste   kivy=1.8.0
-Fetching package metadata ...............
 Solving package specifications: .
 UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in    conflict:
 - kivy 1.8.0* -> python 2.7*
 - python 3.6*
 Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as it says `Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

Answer (score 5):

maybe is too late, but I had the same problem, just follow the instructions of the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#) (use pip instead of conda in this case)

> 1. Ensure you have the latest pip and wheel:
>
>    `python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools`
> 2. Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~120MB) if not needed, see Kivy’s dependencies):
>
>    `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`
>
>    `python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer`
>
> For Python 3.5 only we additionally offer angle which can be used
>   instead of glew and can be installed with:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
> ```
>
> 3. Install kivy:
>
>    `python -m pip install kivy`

In the step 2 I had this error: *PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:*

You need to go to the Anaconda folder and disable the 'Read-only' attribute and then run again the Step 2.
I don't know if this is the best way but works for me.